# Footer cut off in review tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, footer

This first image is from the newest questions tab on ELU SE. It shows how the footer should be.

[image: Normal Footer]

This is the bugged one. When I scroll down, it pops back up and I can never see further down than shown. This occurred on the Review First Posts tab.

[image: Bugged footer]

It only occurs on answers as far as I can tell. Also, it doesn't occur on the first review I do; just the ones afterwards.

Comment: It happens on other sites as well.

Comment: Is suspected that, but that was the only review queue in which I have enough rep to review and has questions in it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new footer, I can not reproduce.

Setting this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).